# When I call `self.ui.action1.triggered.connect(self.Insert)` the program doesn't react anything

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyuic

When I call `self.ui.action1.triggered.connect(self.Insert)` the program doesn't react anything.
(1 is PyQt ui object)
Here's the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import mainwindow
import sys
import subprocess as sub
import LayoutUI
import SetDirUi
import aboutdia
**import edui                   #edui.py**
import Selectoruiu

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        loadUi(r"D:\folder visead\RAIN FORREST\Data Base\Citizen record\Citizen_database.ui", self)

        self.ui.actionDocumentation_2.triggered.connect(self.docOpen)
        self.ui.actionLayout.triggered.connect(self.CallLayout)
        self.ui.actionDatabase_directory.triggered.connect(self.CallNdirSetting)
        self.ui.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self.CallAbout)
        self.ui.actionEdit.triggered.connect(self.Edit)
**        self.ui.action1.triggered.connect(self.Insert) #Problem here**

    def docOpen(self):
        try:
            sub.call("cscript Normal.vbs")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening documentation: {e}")

    def CallLayout(self):
        self.LayUi = LayoutUI.MyApp() 
        self.LayUi.show()

    def CallNdirSetting(self):
        self.DirUi = SetDirUi.MyApp() 
        self.DirUi.show()        

    def CallAbout(self):
        self.AboutUi = aboutdia.MyApp()
        self.AboutUi.show()

    def Edit(self):
        try:
            self.SelectUi = Selectoruiu.MyApp()
            self.SelectUi.show()
            with open("GateawayOntime.txt", "wt") as f:
                writer = "edit"
                f.write(writer)
            print(writer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in Edit: {e}")

 **   def Insert(self):                               #Function that was calling
        try:
                self.uie = edui.MyApp()
                self.uie.show()
                with open("GateawayOntime.txt", "wt") as f:
                    writer = "insert"
                    f.write(writer)
                print(writer)
        except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in Insert: {e}")
**
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mapp = MyApp()
    mapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It should pop the Editor ui (`import edui`) as the content of the `Insert()` function defined.

Comment: The first 5 lines of the `__init__` are just completely *wrong*. 1. you're inheriting from QMainWindow, so you should call the init for *that* base class, not that of QWidget; 2. then you call *again* the base implementation, but with `super()`, which doesn't make sense: you either use `QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)` or `super().__init__(parent)`, ***not both***; 3. you've already set up the UI using a pyuic class, but `loadUi` does the same with the ui file, thus overwriting any previously set UI: you either do use the pyuic class, or call `loadUi`, ***not both***.